# WSO2 EI 6.0 non blocking local transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've been following [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Local+Transport) from wso2 documentation in order to enable non blocking local transport for my project, but after restarting the server I'm unable to log in the management console.
In the console, I have the following error output:

```
[2017-04-18 11:55:56,039] []  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://10.1.2.68:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin]
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
        at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:193)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:659)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:195)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    ...
```

Can anyone shed a light on what is wrong with my configuration? I have followed the doc instructions step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some port issues in EI 600 and please use EI 610 [1]. It working properly with local transport scenario. And please use these documentations  [2, 3] as EI having some directory changes.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/About+this+Release
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Local+Transport
[3]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Sample+268%3A+Proxy+Services+with+the+Local+Transport

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tryied updating to EI 610, but the problem with the management console persists.